# How does the founder exercise work?

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, yoga, back-pain

I sometimes experience discomfort and pain in the lower back.

I deadlift a heavy set once a week.
This does not seem to be helping. And why should it? It makes my lower back able to stabilize against very heavy loads for a very short period of time. My daily life probably involves stabilizing against a light load for very long periods of time instead (could this be called postural strength?).

There is a bodyweight exercise called
[the founder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kp84tCkNiFg) that I believe will help. I will start doing this once a day.

But I would also like to know;
why and how does this exercise work? Or does it not work?
Is it roughly equivalent to a barbell only romanian deadlift?

My theory is that in order to avoid back pain one must have great muscular endurance in the lower back and flexibility and muscular endurance in the hamstrings. One way to achieve this would be do a lot (say 100 reps a week) of very light deadlifts or RDLs. The founder is roughly the same as a deadlift or RDL where one uses the arms as weight instead of a bar. A few set of heavy deadlifts a week does not cut it. What is needed is muscular endurance not strength. That does not exclude heavy deadlifts. They are useful. In the case I may have to lift eg. a washing machine.

Comment: One reason this question is hard to answer is that you're asking four different things: the relationship of deadlifting to postural strength, *how* the founder exercise works, *whether* it works for postural strength, whether it's a "minimum viable solution for the core" (whatever that means), and its relationship to deadlifts & RDLs. I think it needs some work to really be answerable.

Comment: I have narrowed it down a bit. Thank you for your answer and comment.

Comment: What is the volume and intensity of your heavy deadlift set?

Comment: Working set: 5 reps. As heavy as I can. 3 warm-up sets of say 7 reps each.

Comment: *"why and how does this exercise work?"* -- it might be because they've convinced you to do it daily whereas you deadlift once a week? Maybe crank up the deadlift volume and the number of days per week (e.g. 3x8 deadlifts three times a week).

Comment: "As heavy as I can" means very very very different things to different people. A deadlift below or around bodyweight is simply not the same exercise as a deadlift at 1.5-2xBW. They have very different effects on the body.

Comment: @Dave: this sounds silly. I am pretty sure by "intensity" C. Lange meant % of 1 RM. I should have answered 85%. My 1RM deadlift is only 0.9 of my bodyweight BTW. Are you saying that as this weight goes up the nature of the deadlift changes? If so how? Are other muscles trained? Or are you saying that since you deadlift more than me you are right and I am wrong? It may be a factor I admit. But how old are you? Are you old enough to have back pain?

Comment: @ C. Lange: yes exactly! But the problem is that because of CNS fatigue one cannot train heavy deadlift every day. Light deadlifts on the other hand should be OK. 3 times a week may also be OK at least if one of the days are speed lifts (50 % intensity).

Comment: A 0.9xBW 1RM deadlift does not provide the benefits of deadlifting. It simply doesn't. Stop all this dancing around and just focus on that for a full minute. Yes, the nature changes, DRAMATICALLY. The benefits to postural strength, added muscle protecting the lumbar spine, strength to bodyweight ratio, muscles *challenged* rather than just *used* casually, simply haven't kicked in yet! But all these words aren't helpful, especially for you. Stop thinking about it and **go do it** so you can feel it yourself.

Comment: @Dave: thank you for your persistence. What BW ratio do you think is a minimum to enjoy these benefits? Will 1.25 x BW suffice? My initial goal was 1.5 x BW but that seems like a bit of a stretch. May take some time. Do you  think I should add a speed deadlift day with 50%-60% effort once a week to speed-up progress? Cressey recommends this in his book Maximum Strength.

Comment: I usually recommend able-bodied adult males aim for 2xBW. They usually start to understand at 1.5xBW. That's about 25 to 35 jumps in weight, going 2.5 or 5kg at a time. You can make those jumps at least once a week. That's six or eight months if you're consistent. I don't have an opinion on Cressey's recommendation. I do think that deadlifting more than once a week is necessary. One session could be RDLs. Don't forget to eat properly. Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I deadlift a heavy set once a week. This does not seem to be helping [my posture and back discomfort]. And why should it?

Because if your max deadlift is 60kg then maintaining proper posture against a light load is a large fraction of your strength and therefore can't last long, whereas if your max deadlift is 120kg then maintaining proper posture against the same light load is a negligible fraction of your strength and can therefore be maintained for a long time.

Deadlifting and squatting heavy also adds muscle to the back that changes your *default* posture drastically for the better.

Most people who are just beginning to deadlift often experience more lower back soreness than they've ever imagined. Instead of leaning into the experience, pushing through for a few months, and developing a strong back, they slow down, back off, and therefore never get the benefit of a strong deadlift. It takes a while for the postural benefits of heavy squatting and deadlifting to kick in, but they're definitely there.

It's of course possible to be quite strong and experience back pain, but the relationship of deadlifting to that problem is different for strong versus weak people. Weak people need to get strong and re-evaluate; strong people need to stay strong and develop practices like daily yoga/warm-ups/mobility circuits.

Without knowing how much someone is lifting and how seriously they're taking the practice, it's difficult to know why they aren't feeling the benefits. Your question history makes me wonder if you are over-analyzing the situation, looking for easy alternatives to a hard practice that would work if you just let it. But you've also been lifting for over a year, so hopefully you've reached some serious strength benchmarks and you just need a mobility practice.

Comment: I am planning on doing both a set of heavy deadlift a week and this exercise.
I found this article: https://yogainternational.com/article/view/back-health-why-endurance-matters-more-than-strength
It mentions that according to Dr. Stuart M. McGill "the strongest positive correlation is between the endurance of the back muscles and the health of our spine." You mention that "if your max deadlift is 60kg then maintaining proper posture against a light load is a large fraction of your strength 
and therefore can't last long". I think this is where you are wrong.

Comment: The principle "increasing strength makes submaximal lifts easier" is valid but only within a narrow range.
Brzycky 1 RM equation is only valid up to 10 repetitions. 10 repetions equals a 25 % reduction in weight.
So if you can do 9 pushups increasing your 1 RM narrow bench will make you able to do more pushups.
If you can do 20 pushups however increasing your 1 RM narrow bench will not make you able to do more pushups.
McGills conclusion indicates that maintaining proper posture only take a very small fraction of the strength needed in deadlift.

Comment: Please watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDXiHzBzbnA and jump to 3 minutes. Here you will see how Matt Wenning performs 300 hamstring curls a week. He deadlifts 340 kgs so evidently a strong deadlift is not enough to have strong and flexible hamstrings and avoid back pain.

Comment: You do you. Experiment away with this exercise.

Comment: Thank you for your help Dave! I have deadlifted almost regularly since this question and have not experienced any backpain. So in my experience you are a 100% correct.

Comment: @Andy That's awesome! Great work and congratulations! :)